# Adicionar Gancho Woocommerce para acrescentar atributo target

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Preciso criar um ganho em meu functions.php para alterar a função `woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open`do plugin Woocommerce.

A função original é:

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';}
```

Quero que ela fique assim:

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" target="_parent">';}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver com uma dica do próprio autor do plugin Woocommerce.

O mesmo me respondeu:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item',
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION_NAME', 10 );
```

Com isso fui até o `functions.php`do meu tema filho e adicionei o seguinte código:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item',
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item',
'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open_personalizado', 10 );

function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open_personalizado() {
echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link" target="_parent">';
}
```

Isso resolveu a minha questão, não sei se é a melhor opção, mas foi a dica que um dos autores do Woocommerce enviou. Segue o link da resposta: https://goo.gl/6rVM9z

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de resolver seu problema, sem precisar alterar a função é usando javascript desta forma, no caso usei jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('body a').each(function(i, el){

     var linksParents = ["/url/home/","/categoria/123"];
        $(el).attr('id', 'link_'+i);
        if ($.inArray(el.attr('href'), linksParents) ) {
           $(el).attr('target', '_parent');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: eu tentei usar este código, mas não funcionou;